# Android - PackageManager flags

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am going through the PackageManager API. I find the following constants defined :

```
1) GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS
2) GET_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED_COMPONENTS
3) COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED
4) COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_USER
5) COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED
6) COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT
7) COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
8) GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES
```

On reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html), I see that for constants 5-7 a component has be enabled / disabled regardless of how it is specified in the manifest file.

For 3, the documentations says :

```
This application should be considered, until the point where the user actually
wants to use it.
```

What does this mean ?

For 4, the documentations says :

```
The user has explicitly disabled the application, regardless of what it has 
specified in its manifest.
```

If this flag relates to the application, why does the name start with 'COMPONENT' ? Also how does user disable the application ?

For 8, the documentation says :

```
Flag parameter to retrieve some information about all applications (even 
uninstalled ones) which have data directories. This state could have 
resulted if applications have been deleted with flag DONT_DELETE_DATA with 
a possibility of being replaced or reinstalled in future.
```

Where is the DONT_DELETE_DATA flag specified ?

In all, if someone could please explain use cases of these constants for developers, it would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use them in a project of mine. Check it out here. https://github.com/slightfoot/android-launcher-badges

Not sure if it helps.

Edit:
You'll see most of the flags being used here: [AppBadge.java](https://github.com/slightfoot/android-launcher-badges/blob/master/src/com/demondevelopers/launcherbadges/AppBadge.java) The rest are pretty self explanatory. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) seems to describe everything quite well.

3. **COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED** *(Added in API level 18)*

   The example it mentions seems' to be quite adequate in explaining a possible use case.

   > Flag for `setApplicationEnabledSetting(String, int, int)` only: This application should be considered, until the point where the user actually wants to use it. This means that it will not normally show up to the user (such as in the launcher), but various parts of the user interface can use `GET_DISABLED_UNTIL_USED_COMPONENTS` to still see it and allow the user to select it (as for example an IME, device admin, etc). Such code, once the user has selected the app, should at that point also make it enabled. This option currently can not be used with `setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName, int, int)`.
4. **COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_USER** *(Added in API level 14)*

   It would seem they have been designed to eventually work with `setComponentEnabledSetting` but currently they cannot. This is for forward compatibility, and the documentation states you can use `setApplicationEnabledSetting`.

   > Flag for `setApplicationEnabledSetting(String, int, int)` only: The user has explicitly disabled the application, regardless of what it has specified in its manifest. Because this is due to the user's request, they may re-enable it if desired through the appropriate system UI. This option currently cannot be used with `setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName, int, int)`.
5. **DONT_DELETE_DATA** flag was renamed to **DELETE_KEEP_DATA** and the documentation has not been updated. It has been marked as `@hide` because its not for public developer use.

   ```
   /**
    * Flag parameter for {@link #deletePackage} to indicate that you don't want to delete the
    * package's data directory.
    *
    * @hide
    */
   public static final int DELETE_KEEP_DATA = 0x00000001;
   ```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the use case in your project. Which flag you use and please explain the ambiguous meaning of above flags.